# wsHttpBinding configuration

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I was reading a wcf book and come accross the following code block

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ProductsServiceWSHttpBindingConfig">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I'm confused with the `<transport ....>` and `<message ...>`
I did onlne search and was able to conclude meaning of each. But, not sure what will be the outcome of this code block. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are going to configure security for `WsHttpBinding` you first have to choose how the communication will be secured. That is configured by `mode` in security `element`:

- `None` - no security and authentication
- `Transport` - communication will be encrypted on transport level (HTTPS) and authentication will be done on transport level as well (through HTTP headers)
- `TransportWithMessageCredential` - communication will be encrypted on transport level (HTTPS) and authentication will be done on message level (trough standardized SOAP headers)
- `Message` - each message will be separately encrypted and signed following WS-Security standards and send over HTTP and authentication will be done on message level as well. Encryption, signing and authentication use standardized SOAP headers.

Once you defined `mode` you can use `transport` and `message` elements to further specify details of security used in specific `mode`. The most common setting is `clientCredentialType` which specifies how is client authenticated by the service. `transport` element offers modes available in HTTP protocol and `message` element offers modes specified by WS-Security.

Your configuration defines binding for endpoint using HTTPS and SOAP header (UserName Token) for passing user name and password to the service.

Comment: This is perfect explanation. So, I assume these settings needed when web service will use Forms Authentication.